# Non async method, call async method, and need to work with the result

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, mandrill

I have a syncronized method and class which is static. I have to call Mandrill and use the result.

My method, looks like this

```
public static void MyMethod(Association association , Person p)
    {
        MandrillApi mandrill = new MandrillApi(mandrillAPIKey);
        var mail = GetMandrillMessage(fromEmail, clubAdmin.ProfileInfo.Email);

        mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
        mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
        mail.AddGlobalVariable("AssociationBaseUrl", SettingsHelper.GetSetting("AssociationBaseUrl"));
        mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
        mail.AddGlobalVariable("UserFirstname", clubAdmin.Firstname);

        mail.Subject = "Subject goes here";
        var messageRequest = new SendMessageTemplateRequest(mail, "template");
        var result = mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest);
    }
```

I need result.Result. I can't make my method to async.

So is there any way to get result.Result and use it in a new method?

i was thinking to do something like

```
var messageRequest = new SendMessageTemplateRequest(mail, "template");
var result = mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest);
CallMyMethod(result.Result.First().Id)
```

but this wont work, it will just stop the program. Really need help. Ask for more information. I am really bad at explaining myself.

Comment: Ideally `MyMethod()` *should* be `async`.  Why can't it be in this case?

Comment: If `mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest)` returns a `Task` you can call `result.Wait()` and then return `result.Result`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria IIRC this does exactly the same as just calling `.Result`. In this case he is probably running into a deadlock. Here is a good article on `async`/`await`, `Wait()` and deadlocks: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @David. i was told that the class and all the methods in it, should remain syncronized. I'm sorry that i can't provide a better answer.  I would wish that i could make i async

Comment: @Mags If your instructions were to not call any asynchronous methods, then you can't call any asynchronous methods.  So don't call the asynchronous methods that you're currently calling.

Comment: "but this wont work, it will just stop the program. Really need help. Ask for more information. I am really bad at explaining myself." what do you mean with wont work? What's the error message/ Exception thrown?

Comment: @Crowcoder You can most certainly cause a deadlock on a `void` returning method.  You'd do it identically to how you would in any other type of method.

Comment: @Crowcoder And how is that relevant to this question?  There is no asynchronous void returning method that never synchronously waits on another asynchronous method in this question.  The only criteria that the method in this question meets is that it's void returning.

Comment: I *think* I can shine some light on what the OP is actually asking. They are calling [`IMandrillApi.SendMessageTemplate`](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/IMandrillApi.cs) which returns a `Task<T>`. They want to get the result from the Task *but* their existing call stack is synchronous. Likely the OP is having trouble (deadlock or exception) when calling `.Result` on the returned `Task`.

Comment: @Crowcoder i call the method from controller method
MailHelper.SendMessageFromAssociationMail(senderProfileInfo.Associations.First(), recipient.Persons.First(), model.MessageModel.Text);

Comment: @Crowcoder But if it did what the OP said it was doing then it would cause a deadlock.  So your point that it can't deadlock, when it both can, and appears to have been doing just that, is wrong.  If the method was asynchornous, which it was not, and wasn't synchronously blocking on an asynchronous method, which it was, and wasn't calling a method that was deadlocking, which we can't know the answer to, then sure, it wouldn't deadlock.  None of those things are true though.

Comment: @Mags - Why not make your call stack (starting at the controller's action method) asynchronous in this case? That would be tho correct way to handle this and (depending on how deep this call is in that stack) *should* not be too much, if any at all, work.

Comment: Info to all. My method does not throw an exception. if i debug, i will just remain in the method. ex
var result = mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest);
var test = result.Result.First().Id - it will just stand here doing nothing

Comment: @Mags - That is called a Deadlock.

Comment: @Igor Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: @Mags - Yes, exactly what I wrote in my second comment about making the call stack asynchronous.

Comment: @Igor is there any solution without changing the callstack to asynchronous?

What if i want to keep all changes local, to that one class and method. My callstack is,

Controller - doing som logic - Then calling my method, MailHelper.MyMethod()

I want to keep all changes in My Mailhelper class

Comment: @Mags - Why the, IMO unreasonable, constraint of not using async/await in the call stack? Change the controllers method to return `Task` (or `Task<T>`), change `MyMethod` to return `Task` (or `Task<T>`), and then use `async/await` in both methods and the problem should be solved. It is quick and easy to implement and there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a deadlock. The correct wait to call asynchronous code from synchronous code is to make your whole call stack (starting at the controller's action method) asynchronous. IMO not doing this is an unreasonable constraint.

Changes:

- Make `MyMethod` return `Task` instead of `void` so it can be awaited
- Add `async` to `MyMethod`
- Add `await` to wait for the result from `IMandrilApi.SendMessageTemplate`
- Rename `MyMethod` to `MyMethodAsync`, not required but it follows a commonly accepted naming convention
- Make controller method async and return a `Task`. If the controller is returning something then return `Task<T>` where `T` is the current return type.
- Controller method `await`s the result of `MyMethodAsync`

---

```
public static async Task MyMethodAsync(Association association , Person p)
{
    /* your existing code has been removed for brevity as there are no changes in that code */
    var result = await mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest);
}
```

**Controller method**

*I had to make an assumption this code but you did state in the comments the call stack is controller → MyMethod. Also note that only the relevant part to the question is shown and I had no other info to go on.*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task SendMessage()
{
   await MyMethodAsync(association, person);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put your method to a `Task` and `await` it

```
public static object MyMethod(Association association , Person p)
{
    MandrillApi mandrill = new MandrillApi(mandrillAPIKey);
    var mail = GetMandrillMessage(fromEmail, clubAdmin.ProfileInfo.Email);

    mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
    mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
    mail.AddGlobalVariable("AssociationBaseUrl", SettingsHelper.GetSetting("AssociationBaseUrl"));
    mail.AddGlobalVariable("Key", value);
    mail.AddGlobalVariable("UserFirstname", clubAdmin.Firstname);

    mail.Subject = "Subject goes here";
    var messageRequest = new SendMessageTemplateRequest(mail, "template");
    var result = mandrill.SendMessageTemplate(messageRequest);
    return result;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]MyObject obj)
{
   var task = Task.Run(() => MyMethod(a,p));   
   var result = await task;

   return Request.CreateResponse(...);
}
```

But `async` in the controller does not make the user experience `async`. User will have to wait as long as task finishes. So why do we do async ?

Comment: @ThierryV Thanks for the comment, i cant use your solution. My class is called from a HttpPost controller

Comment: I will try your solution. Thank you!